# How to fix android based Firebase error while deleting objects causing an infinite loop?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, infinite-loop

I am developing an app using Firebase. In one of my activities, I have added a delete functionality. But when I delete a node and monitor the behaviour in the Firebase console.

First it deletes the object, adds 2 more. Then deletes the 2, adds 3-4 more. This operation continues to such an extent that the device becomes unstable (gets stuck in an infinite loop). The app causes the screen to go completely black. Nothing works. Logcat shows "too much output to process." Navigation buttons takes the user back the the unstable app.

It does not Uninstall. The only solution is to force reboot it. The code used to do this operation was

```
mChatsListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            chatToDelete = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sender_roll_text_view)).getText().toString().trim();
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChatsActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Delete Chat?").setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Query query = mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("roll").equalTo(chatToDelete);
                    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                dataSnapshot1.getRef().removeValue();
                                chats.remove(position);
                                mChatsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                    });
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This code was working fine just yesterday. But now it is a huge problem. So, please do help if you figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Not knowing much about Firebase, I would hazard a guess that either the `removeValue()` or the `notifyDataSetChanged()` causes a new `onDataChange()` event. Perhaps use an [`AtomicBoolean`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) to detect re-entry?

Answer (score 0):

I think it happen because you use `addValueEventListener` instead of `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`. By using `addValueEventListener`the `onDataChange` will be triggered every time database is changed.

Inside `onClick` please change from

`query.addValueEventListener` to `query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent`

This should solve your problem

Comment: I have been using addListenerForSingleValueEvent only.

Comment: But according to your code it's `addValueEventListener` not `addListenerForSingleValueEven` please have a look closely.

Comment: Sorry. I guess I gave the previous version of the code. In the newer version I am using addListenerForSingleValueEvent () but that doesn't fix the error

Comment: Did you solve the problem? if not please update your code so that i could help.